# alternative to PySerial while openings serial ports on Debian Linux with python

Tags: python, serial-port, debian, pyserial

I am having issues with PySerial. I am getting `OSError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable` within PySerial's `serialposix.py`.  I am wondering if there is any alternative way of reading data within python from a serial port to help determine if it is a python issue of something within the OS. I am running Debian 6.

Comment: Generally when you're having issues with a popular and well-tested library, switching to an alternative won't make life easier.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko I know, I have used PySerial in the past with success. Mainly on window based systems however. I have been trying to find the source of the error but have not been successful, which is why I am asking for an alternative to test. I agree when it comes to well-tested libraries, 99.9% of the time errors are caused by the library user. I am just trying to eliminate that .1% of a chance its not me.

Comment: Ever find an alternative?